# gdb can't cross-compile for arm-linux

Tags: linux, arm, gdb, autotools, autoconf

The Linux already having both `gcc` & `arm-gcc` in the environment path:

```
[fit@localhost gdb-arm]$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-cpu=generic --build=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8) (GCC) 


[fit@localhost gdb-arm]$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-none-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /scratch/mitchell/builds/4.3-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-respin/src/gcc-4.3/configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --enable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-specs='%{funwind-tables|fno-unwind-tables|mabi=*|ffreestanding|nostdlib:;:-funwind-tables}' --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-pkgversion='Sourcery G++ Lite 2009q1-203' --with-bugurl=https://support.codesourcery.com/GNUToolchain/ --disable-nls --prefix=/opt/codesourcery --with-sysroot=/opt/codesourcery/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc --with-build-sysroot=/scratch/mitchell/builds/4.3-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-respin/lite/install/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc --with-gmp=/scratch/mitchell/builds/4.3-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-respin/lite/obj/host-libs-2009q1-203-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpfr=/scratch/mitchell/builds/4.3-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-respin/lite/obj/host-libs-2009q1-203-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --disable-libgomp --enable-poison-system-directories --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/mitchell/builds/4.3-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-respin/lite/install/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/mitchell/builds/4.3-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-respin/lite/install/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.3.3 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2009q1-203)
```

So I configure the `gdb 6.6`:

```
$ ./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=i386-redhat-linux -v
```

compiled without error, but looks like gdb used the wrong compiler.

```
file ./gdb-build/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb
./gdb-build/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

So How to indicate the correct CC for gdb?

I tried `make CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, but will get the error:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ../.././sim/arm/../common/gentmap.c -o gentmap -g -O -I. -I../.././sim/arm -I../common -I../.././sim/arm/../common -I../../include -I../.././sim/arm/../../include -I../../bfd -I../.././sim/arm/../../bfd -I../../opcodes -I../.././sim/arm/../../opcodes  
rm -f tmp-tvals.h tmp-tmap.c
./gentmap -h >tmp-tvals.h
/bin/sh: ./gentmap: cannot execute binary file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=i386-redhat-linux -v
> ```

Don't use `--target`. It means something else to Autotools.

Use `--build` and `--host`. Something like:

```
./configure --build=$(config.guess) --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
```

`--build` should specify the machine you are running Autotools on, and `--host` should specify the machine the package will run on.

Note there is some Autootols bug that requires you to specify both `--build` and `--host`. It is yet another Autotools problem that has never been fixed.

Also see [2.2.8, Cross-Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html) in the Autools manual.

You will still need to get the paths and sysroot right, but this should provide the proper configure command so things begin to fail as expected.

---

`config.guess` will return a triplet for the machine you are running Autotools on:

```
$ find /usr/share/ -name config.guess
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/config.guess
...

$ /usr/share/libtool/build-aux/config.guess
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

If you find the package has one but it is out of date you can update it with the following command. You usually need to do this for AIX and Solaris machines.

```
wget 'https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess' -O config.guess
```

And you can update `config.sub` the same way:

```
wget 'https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub' -O config.sub
```

Comment: Thanks! now it looks like using the right CC. But got a new error: `configure: error: no termcap library found`. any idea about this?

Comment: @Jiu - Does your sysroot have termcap or ncurses? If not, then you need to disable it (is that possible?) or build the prerequisites and install them in sysroot. In the end you may have a collection of scripts to build the prereqs like [Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts).