# occur struct redefined while cross compiled gdb 8.2

Tags: linux, gdb, cross-compiling

I wanna cross compile the gdb 8.2 into the one arm64 device.
here is my steps to do:

1. mkdir build && cd build.
2. ../configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu
3. make

then I got the redefined error and the member-undefined from the output.

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:40:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _fpx_sw_bytes’
   40 | struct _fpx_sw_bytes {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:291,
                 from build-gnulib/import/signal.h:52,
                 from ../../gdb/linux-nat.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigcontext.h:31:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct _fpx_sw_bytes’
   31 | struct _fpx_sw_bytes
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-ptrace.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:35:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:85:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _fpreg’
   85 | struct _fpreg {
      |        ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:291,
                 from build-gnulib/import/signal.h:52,
                 from ../../gdb/linux-nat.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigcontext.h:40:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct _fpreg’
   40 | struct _fpreg
      |        ^~~~~~
In file included from ../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-ptrace.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:35:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:91:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _fpxreg’
   91 | struct _fpxreg {
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:291,
                 from build-gnulib/import/signal.h:52,
                 from ../../gdb/linux-nat.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigcontext.h:46:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct _fpxreg’
   46 | struct _fpxreg
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from ../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-ptrace.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:35:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:98:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _xmmreg’
   98 | struct _xmmreg {
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:291,
                 from build-gnulib/import/signal.h:52,
                 from ../../gdb/linux-nat.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigcontext.h:53:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct _xmmreg’
   53 | struct _xmmreg
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from ../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-ptrace.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:35:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:180:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _ymmh_state’
  180 | struct _ymmh_state {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:291,
                 from build-gnulib/import/signal.h:52,
                 from ../../gdb/linux-nat.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigcontext.h:184:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct _ymmh_state’
  184 | struct _ymmh_state
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-ptrace.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:35:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:192:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _xstate’
  192 | struct _xstate {
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:291,
                 from build-gnulib/import/signal.h:52,
                 from ../../gdb/linux-nat.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigcontext.h:189:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct _xstate’
  189 | struct _xstate
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from ../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-ptrace.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:35:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:317:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct sigcontext’
  317 | struct sigcontext {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:291,
                 from build-gnulib/import/signal.h:52,
                 from ../../gdb/linux-nat.h:23,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigcontext.h:139:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct sigcontext’
  139 | struct sigcontext
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-ptrace.h:29,
                 from ../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:35:
../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-sigcontext.h:25:22: error: field ‘head’ has incomplete type ‘_aarch64_ctx’
   25 |  struct _aarch64_ctx head;
      |                      ^~~~
../../gdb/nat/aarch64-sve-linux-sigcontext.h:25:9: note: forward declaration of ‘struct _aarch64_ctx’
   25 |  struct _aarch64_ctx head;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c: In function ‘void fetch_fpregs_from_thread(regcache*)’:
../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:320:37: error: ‘elf_fpregset_t’ {aka ‘struct user_fpregs_struct’} has no member named ‘vregs’
  320 |  regcache->raw_supply (regno, &regs.vregs[regno - AARCH64_V0_REGNUM]);
      |                                     ^~~~~
../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:322:56: error: ‘elf_fpregset_t’ {aka ‘struct user_fpregs_struct’} has no member named ‘fpsr’
  322 |       regcache->raw_supply (AARCH64_FPSR_REGNUM, &regs.fpsr);
      |                                                        ^~~~
../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:323:56: error: ‘elf_fpregset_t’ {aka ‘struct user_fpregs_struct’} has no member named ‘fpcr’
  323 |       regcache->raw_supply (AARCH64_FPCR_REGNUM, &regs.fpcr);
      |                                                        ^~~~
../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c: In function ‘void store_fpregs_to_thread(const regcache*)’:
../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:368:29: error: ‘elf_fpregset_t’ {aka ‘struct user_fpregs_struct’} has no member named ‘vregs’
  368 |      (regno, (char *) &regs.vregs[regno - AARCH64_V0_REGNUM]);
      |                             ^~~~~
../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:371:61: error: ‘elf_fpregset_t’ {aka ‘struct user_fpregs_struct’} has no member named ‘fpsr’
  371 |  regcache->raw_collect (AARCH64_FPSR_REGNUM, (char *) &regs.fpsr);
      |                                                             ^~~~
../../gdb/aarch64-linux-nat.c:373:61: error: ‘elf_fpregset_t’ {aka ‘struct user_fpregs_struct’} has no member named ‘fpcr’
  373 |  regcache->raw_collect (AARCH64_FPCR_REGNUM, (char *) &regs.fpcr);
      |                                                             ^~~~
```

and the most strange thing is, if I don't configure the --host=aarch64-linux-gnu, the compiling is OK.
but I wanna put the "gdb" into my developing board, how could I resolve this error?

Comment: Given the error is about a something defined in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h`, which is clearly an x86-64 header, I would guess the problem is your cross compiler setup is not correct in some way - the compiler is picking up the wrong headers.  Without the `--host` configure option GDB will be built for an x86-64 host, but with support for debugging aa4ch64 targets (via remote protocol), in that case the cross-compiler will not be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gdb can't cross-compile for arm-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472127/gdb-cant-cross-compile-for-arm-linux)

Comment: @Andrew maybe you are right ,but how can I fix this error? I didn't find any article about configuring to use the cross-tool-chains headers ,but not x86-64 head files.